# send array of data from POJO to JSP

Tags: arrays, jsp, pojo

I had a problem on printing array of data in JSP, heres what happend.
I created a POJO called: popArayCustOrd

```
   public class popAryCustOrd {
          public String prodkey,descrp,strgth,stkunt;
          double rprice;
          int quantity;

    popAryCustOrd(String prodkey,String descrp,int quantity,Double rprice,String stkunt,String strgth){
    this.prodkey = prodkey;
    this.descrp = descrp;
    this.quantity = quantity;
    this.rprice = rprice;
    this.stkunt = stkunt;
    this.strgth = strgth;

}
public void setProdkey(String prodkey){
    this.prodkey = prodkey;
}
public String  getProdkey(){
    return(this.prodkey);
}
public void setDescrp(String descrp){
    this.descrp = descrp;
}
public String getDescrp(){
    return(this.descrp);
}
public void setQuantity(int quantity){
    this.quantity = quantity;
}
public int getQuantity(){
    return(this.quantity);
}
public void setRprice(double rprice){
    this.rprice = rprice;
}
public double getRprice(){
    return(this.rprice);
}
public void setStkunt(String stkunt){
    this.stkunt = stkunt;
}
public String getStkunt(){
    return(this.stkunt);
}
public void setStrgth(String strgth){
    this.strgth = strgth;
}
public String getStrgth(){
    return(this.strgth);
}
```

}

and in my servlet file called seekprod.java I assigned data coming from the database within a method....

```
      connx.rs.beforeFirst();
           while(connx.rs.next()){
              popAryCustOrd[] prodList = new popAryCustOrd[]{new                                 popAryCustOrd(connx.rs.getString("prodkey"),connx.rs.getString("descrp"),connx.rs.getInt("quantity"),connx.rs.getDouble("retailp"),connx.rs.getString("stkunit"),connx.rs.getString("strength"))};
                        request.setAttribute("prodList", prodList);

                    }

                     RequestDispatcher dispatcher =        request.getRequestDispatcher("preOrdFrm.jsp? inKey="+this.inKey+"&transkey=drugs");
                     dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

.......

and my JSP to access the data is.....

```
    <c:forEach items="${prodList}" var="paramx" >
       <tr>
         <td>${paramx.prodkey}</td>
         <td style="text-align: center; word-wrap: break-word; word-break:break-all; text-overflow: ellipsis;overflow:hidden;white-space: normal; white-space: -webkit-pre-wrap;">${paramx.descrp}</td>
     <td>${paramx.stkunt}</td>
     <td>${paramx.strgth}</td>
     <td>${paramx.rprice}</td>
     <td>${paramx.quantity}</td>
     <td><input type="hidden" name="agentId" value="<%=uID %>">
     <input type="hidden" name="pcode" value=${paramx.prodkey}>
     <input type="hidden" name="inKey" value=${param.inKey}>
     <input type="hidden" name="transKey" value="sveOrd">
     <input style="font-size:50px; height:55px; width:100px" type="number" name="desqty" min="1" required="" value="1"/></td>
     <td><input style="font-size:20px; height:55px; width:100px" type="submit" name="transact" value="Save"/></td>
                                         </tr>
                                         </c:forEach>
```

eventually it works but I got only one result instead of three records from the database table, my syntax in sql is correct and i checked it many times and compared with the result. I dont know where part of my code to fix. Im very much glad if you could help me .?

Answer (score 0):

```
while(connx.rs.next()){
            popAryCustOrd[] prodList = new popAryCustOrd[]{new
    popAryCustOrd(connx.rs.getString("prodkey"),connx.rs.getString("descrp"),connx.rs.getInt("quantity"),connx.rs.getDouble("retailp"),connx.rs.getString("stkunit"),connx.rs.getString("strength"))};

        request.setAttribute("prodList", prodList);
 }
```

think about this code it sets and then  resets `prodList` attribute in the `request` object with every loop execution, so your jsp will recieve only the last value set to `prodList`.

It would be better to initialize an `ArrayList` outside the loop and add values to it and then after the loop use that list to set the attribute `prodList` in `request` object.